# Prevent HTML escaping in a text area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, security, html-escape-characters

Realized that if I put HTML code in a rails text area, it will output the html.

For instance:

```
<b> Hello </b>
```

outputs as:

**Hello**

I thought rails 3 text inputs automatically escape HTML but whenever I output @variable.textarea, it still shows the bold text. Is it being selective about what HTML to input? And how do I make sure all HTML is always escape when I output the content of my textarea?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused by your question but maybe it's just me. You do or do not want the data to be escaped when an user submits information in a textarea.

Comment: What version of rails are you using? A rails 3 app should automatically escape html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `<b>hello</b>` comes out as **hello**, that means HTML escaping *is* already prevented.

Since you don't want users to be able to use HTML in their inputs, you want HTML to be escaped, so that `<b>hello</b>` comes out as `<b>hello</b>`.

In a Rails 3 app, html automatically gets escaped - but you can explicitly escape it using the [h method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296747/whats-the-h-mean-in-h):

```
<%= h my_string %>
```

Comment: your solution worked and thank you for clarifying my poor use of language. Question: if HTML escaping is set to true by default, how come text area shows my <b>hello</b> as **hello** as output? That's what started my confusion in the first place.

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: I honestly don't know why it is not escaping anything. As of rails 3 all output is escaped automatically and only omitted when you explicitly call the `raw` method on it. Do you happen to use that anywhere?