# having trouble to this "playlist_in_list.user.email" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently struggling to understand following piece of line. It is from partials inside views folder.

```
<span>Owner: <%= h(playlist_in_list.user.email)%> </span>
```

particularly following line

```
h(playlist_in_list.user.email)
```

How can we trace above line of code?

Comment: I hope the following Link will help you.



  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296747/whats-the-h-mean-in-h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial was passed a local variable named `playlist_in_list`.

`playlist_in_list` is associated to a `user`

`user` has a method called `email`

My advice: look where the partial is called.

Concerning `h`, it's simply to html escape the result.